# How to make a 2d game with Ascii art assets

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

I am new to game development and have been practicing programming games in godot. I am looking to make a minimalist game that uses simple ascii art however I am unsure if I should use UI elements to represent different elements of the game or if I should make each letter I want to use into a sprite.

Comment: Which way have you tried so far? Are you unsatisfied with the results you've gotten with that method? If so, what specific problem with that method do you need help solving?

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't made an attempt to implement this as I am unsure what I can/should do, I am trying to find the possible methods of doing this.

Comment: You've listed two possible methods of doing this. Try one of them. If it works, you're done. If it has a problem, post here to ask how to solve that problem.

Comment: Okay, will do, thank you for helping me, I'm new to game development and trying to start small but it seems really daunting. I'm going to attempt to use UI elements since the game would be mainly UI (no characters or enemies or anything like that.)

Comment: Using sprites may be beneficial if you want to use characters that not every system supports or if a system has those characters defined with different code points than what you expected. Not sure how likely any system would not support the basic ascii characters/have those at different code points though.

Comment: @milk that should be a matter of giving the UI elements a font resource that has all the characters you need.